# Исключение "нехороших" детей из списка

Tags: python, ооп

У меня есть код, по которому дети должны получать подарки от Санты. У всех есть свои желания (что они хотят получить), но непослушные дети не могут получить никаких подарков, только те, которые были хорошими. И так есть 3 файла: nice.csv и naughty.csv, которые содержат имена детей и страны (страны не имеют значения) и wishlist.csv, в котором есть имена и их пожелания, разделенные запятой.

Это мой код:

```py
class Child:
    """Child."""

    def __init__(self, name, country):
        """Child Constructor."""
        self.name = name
        self.country = country

    def __repr__(self):
        """Representation."""
        return f"{self.name}"


class Gift:
    """Gift."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Gift name Constructor."""
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        """Representation."""
        return f"{self.name}"


class World:
    """World."""

    def __init__(self, nice_file, wishlist_file):
        """Files Constructor."""
        self.nice_file = nice_file
        self.wishlist_file = wishlist_file

    def read_file(self, filename):
        """Read file."""
        result = []
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for line in reader:
                result.append(line)
        return result

    def nice_list(self):
        """Nice children list."""
        nice = []
        for line in self.read_file(self.nice_file):
            name = Child(line[0], line[1])
            nice.append(name)
        return nice

    def wishlist(self):
        """Wishlist."""
        result = {}
        for line in self.read_file(self.wishlist_file):
            wishes = [Gift(x) for x in line[1:]]
            result[line[0]] = wishes
        return result
```

Проблема в том, что у непослушных детей тоже есть свои желания в списке желаний. Я хочу, чтобы непослушных детей не было в конечном результате.

Например:

nice.csv: Миша, Россия

naughty.csv: Маша, Китай

список желаний.csv: Маша,кукла | Миша, робот

Это то, что я хочу получить, и я не знаю, как этого добиться:

```py
{'Миша': робот}
```

Это то, что я получаю, и это неверно:

```py
{'Маша': кукла, 'Миша': робот}
```

Comment: Потрясающий вопрос... ))) ""Нехорошие" дети", "Child constructor" просто чума )))))

Answer (score 2):

Преобразуйте список желаний в словарь, после чего можно воспользоваться таким выражением:

```
bad_childs = ['Маша', 'Миша']
good_childs = ['Ваня', 'Петя']

desires = {'Маша': 'кукла',
           'Ваня': 'робот',
           'Миша': 'собака',
           'Петя': 'машина'}

print({x: y for x, y in desires.items() if x not in bad_childs})
```

Вывод:

> ```
> {'Ваня': 'робот', 
>  'Петя': 'машина'}
> ```